# Jquery Tabs and Bar animation

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to make the slide bar to switch between divs with animation() effect. So far I tried to add animation() on addClass(), but it didn't work. Also I'd like to display different divs in the empty area when I click on a random div from navigation menu.

http://jsbin.com/tapigu/1/edit?html,css,js,output;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".tab.tab1").click(function(){
    $(".active").animate({top: "0px"});
  })
  $(".tab.tab2").click(function(){
    $(".active").animate({top: "78px"});
  })
  $(".tab.tab3").click(function(){
    $(".active").animate({top: "156px"});
  })
  $(".tab.tab4").click(function(){
    $(".active").animate({top: "234px"});
  })
  $(".tab.tab5").click(function(){
    $(".active").animate({top: "312px"});
  })
});
```

```css
#header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:darkorange;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#chater{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 52px;  /* distanta dintre header si chatbar*/
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height:100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color:lightslategrey;
    border-right: 2px solid darkorange;
}

#navtab {
    position: absolute;
    top:52px; /* distanta dintre header si navtab*/
    left:252px;
    width: 72px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: lightslategrey;
    bottom:0px;

}

.tab {
    height:78px;
    width: 78px;
    display:flex;

}

.active
{
    height:78px;
    width: 72px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-right:5px solid darkorange;
    border-radius:2px;
    position: absolute;
}


#slidebar 
{   position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:364px;
    height:78px;
    width: 5px;
    background:darkorange;
    border-radius: 2px;
 
}

#slidediv {
        position:absolute;
    left:324px;
    top:52px;
    height:100%;
    width: 5px;
    background: lightslategrey;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="chater"></div>
<div id='slidediv'>
<div style='display:none' id="slidebar"></div>
</div>
<div id="navtab">
    <div class="active"></div>
    <div class="tab tab1">sal</div>
    <div class="tab tab2">sal</div>
    <div class="tab tab3">sal</div>
    <div class="tab tab4">sal</div>
    <div class="tab tab5">sal</div>
</div>
</body>

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not sliding up or down? Do u know any css proprety for that?

Comment: @Alexandru Is this what you need? http://jsbin.com/xizunicaho/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @Alexandru for the orange border on the right? That's kinda hard to understand

Comment: yeah, but that's easy to understand. When I click on a tab, I want the bar to animate up or down instead of teleporting..

Comment: thanks man, I made it till the end with jquery, but I've never thought this will work as well :D